# How do I fix Desktop after accidentally disabling everything on compizconfig?

Tags: unity, compiz

I've done something really stupid and I don't know what to do. After trying to enable wobbly windows on my Ubuntu 14.10 desktop using Compizconfig, it for some reason removed everything. I can't access the application manager or taskbar and to make matters worse I can't even access the terminal because it's disabled my controls. All I can do now is log in to my guest session. Is there any way to fix this issue in the guest session using the terminal, or am I going to have to reinstall the whole operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (you can also use <kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd> instead of <kbd>F1</kbd>).
Type in your username and password to get a bash shell (or which ever other shell you have).

To reset your settings you can run:

```
rm ~/.gconf ~/.gconfd ~/.metacity ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/.config/dconf -rf
```

A alternate way to get the your shell from the guest account is to use the `su` command.

```
su [username]
```